# Grails Domains: Get by Id not found

Tags: oracle, hibernate, grails, grails-orm, springsource

I have a Job (using Quartz)

A Service method which uses get (for a Domain class)

The problem is: sometimes (1 in a 1000) the domain's get(X) method returns null even if the row with id X exists.

If I use executeQuery or findByX the same problem happens.

Datasource has cache disabled.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you `flushing` the `save()` of the domain if it is in scope of the Quartz Schedule?

Comment: yes, I'm using save(flush:true) always

Comment: Can you share the portion of service where the domain is persisted and fetched? Quartz `execute()` will also be helpful.

Comment: Is it in debug or runtime? Where do you see, in IDEA watches?

Comment: Which environment is this happening?

Comment: This problem occurs in all environments (production too). I'm not using idea, just sublime text. My database is oracle

Comment: Was this issue ever resolved? I'm running into something similar. Unfortunately @moskiteau's recommendation didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem with Quartz. The problem is that Quartz thread keep a connection that is not flushed. To the workaround is to use this in you job:

```
def session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
session.flush()
session.clear()
```